# Why the difference in output?

Tags: c, floating-point

Using the C Code given below (written in Visual Studio):

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float i = 2.0/3.0;
    printf("%5.6f", i);
    return 0;
}
```

produces the output:
0.666667

however when the %5.6f is changed to %5.20f the output changes to :
0.66666668653488159000

My question is why the subtle changes in output for the similar decimal?

Comment: Take a pencil and paper.  Round the longer of the two numbers you have to have only 6 digits after the decimal point.  Get the picture ?

Comment: 0.66666668653488159000 to 6 decimal places is '0.666667', which is what `%5.6` is asking for. Or are you asking why 0.66666668653488159000 is as close to two thirds as the computer can get?

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm asking how 2.0/3.0 is actually stored as 0.66666668653488159000 in the computer system

Answer (score 5):

When you use 32-bit float, the computer represents the result of `2./3.` as 11,184,811 / 16,777,216, which is exactly 0.666666686534881591796875. In the floating-point you are using, numbers are always represented as some integer multiplied by some power of two (which may be a negative power of two). Due to limits on how large the integer can be (when you use `float`, the integer must fit in 24 bits, not including the sign), the closest representable value to 2/3 is 11,184,811 / 16,777,216.

The reason that `printf` with '%5.6f` displays “0.666667” is because “%5.6f” requests just six digits, so the number is rounded at the sixth digit.

The reason that `printf` with `%5.20f` displays “0.66666668653488159000” is that your `printf` implementation “gives up” after 17 digits, figuring that is close enough in some sense. Some implementations of `printf`, which one might argue are better, print the represented value as closely as the requested format permits. In this case, they would display “0.66666668653488159180”, and, if you requested more digits, they would display the exact value, “0.666666686534881591796875”.

(The floating-point format is often presented as a sign, a fraction between 1 [inclusive] and 2 [exclusive], and an exponent, instead of a sign, an integer, and an exponent. Mathematically, they are the same with an adjustment in the exponent: Each number representable with a sign, a 24-bit unsigned integer, and an exponent is equal to some number with a sign, a fraction between 1 and 2, and an adjusted exponent. Using the integer version tends to make proofs easier and sometimes helps explanation.)

Comment: Why does the computer represent it as 11,184,811 / 16,777,216?

Comment: @user2493976: A decision was made to always use a power of two for the scaling. So every floating-point number has the form +f•2**e or –f•2**e for some number f and some exponent e. (There are certain limits on f and e which depend on the format being used.) This provides a reasonable representation of numbers while being not excessively hard for the hardware to implement. E.g., to multiply numbers, the hardware multiplies the f parts, adds the e exponents, and adjusts if the f part grew large enough to affect the exponent.

Comment: @user2493976: In theory, there are alternatives, such as representing numbers as rational numbers p/q, allowing any integers for p/q. But this makes arithmetic hard, as the denominators will tend to grow in size and additional arithmetic must be performed. And other bases for scaling have been tried, such as 16 or 10, but 2 has succeeded for general-purpose use. 10 is still somewhat popular though, for certain purposes, and is available on certain processors with specialized hardware for it.

Comment: Specifically, `11,184,811 / 16,777,216 == 11,184,811 * (2 ** -24)`. So, the binary floating-point representation has an exponent of `-24` and a mantissa of `11,184,811`. @user2493976 read up on IEEE floating point if you want to understand the details.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike integers, which can be represented exactly in any base, relatively few decimal fractions have an exact representation in the base-2 fractional format.

This means that FP integers are exact, and, generally, FP fractions are not.

So for two-digits, say, 0.01 to 0.99, only 0.25, 0.50, and 0.75 (and 0) have exact representations. Normally it doesn't matter as output gets rounded, and really, few if any physical constants are known to the precision available in the format.

Comment: Hmm...thank you for that, but I knew this to an extent as well, what I'd like to know is are those digits "8653488159000" in  0.66666668653488159000 after the first few 0.6666... arbitrary or can we actually figure out what will be printed even before the program is test run on the machine?

Comment: You can figure it out on paper by stepping through the division algorithm in your platform's native floating-point format, but it's much easier just to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you may not have an exact representation of 0.6666666666666666...66667 in floating point.

Comment: Alright, so are the digits appearing after 0.666667 when the specifier is changed to %5.20f arbitrary?

Comment: When you did `%5.6f` you asked for six decimal places.  And it rounded the number to the six decimal places.  So, you get 0.666667.  When you asked for `%5.20`, you wanted 20 decimal places.  So, it tried to satisfy you to 20 places using the bit pattern it had and hence, the discrepancy.

Comment: Thank you, can you elucidate a bit on "the bit pattern it had" ?

Comment: This answer omits what may be a crucial piece of information for a beginner, ie how an apparently simple number such as `2.0/3.0` gets turned into a floating-point number beginning `0.6666` anyway.  It rather assumes that the reader understands that first step while the question suggests OP does not.

Comment: As @HighPerformanceMark has pointed out, you will need to understand the internal representation of the floating point number.  Since you are working with finite number of bits, you cannot go for arbitrary level of precision on those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The the precision is stored in exponential format i.e. like (-/+)ax10^n. If the data type is 32 bit will spend 1 bit for sign, 8 bit for a and  rest for n. So, it doesn't store values after 20th digit after point. So, in this compiler you will never get the correct value.

Comment: 20th *binary* digit, which corresponds roughly to the 7th decimal digit. Also, you can't represent 2/3 in *any* finite binary FP representation, since it's periodic in binary.

Answer (score -1):

float type has only 23 bits to represent part of decimal, 20 is too many.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question in any meaningful way, does it?